# C programs slow startup

Tags: c

Even a simple HelloWorld program is taking about 30 seconds to run. Is there a way to speed up the execution?
I tried it in codeblocks using MinGW. I have also tried it with Borland c++ 5.5 command line tools. In both the cases it took about 20 to 30 seconds to run, however compilation was quick.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    printf("HELLO");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: What is your environment?

Comment: It is not an issue with how fast the program RUNS but how fast it STARTS.

Comment: I guess you are right ddriver; the terminal window opens and then after 20 seconds or so HELLO is printed.

Comment: 20 seconds!!  You are running the program on an abacus?

Comment: I remember having a similar issue many years ago, well it wasn't 30 seconds, but still 4-5 sec pause. I don't remember how I fixed it, but probably with updating the compiler. It is most likely an issue with the platform runtime libraries.

Comment: It's 'Hello world'.  My apps, with GUI, DB, peripheral server and whatever run up in <1 sec.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you running antivirus software? My guess is that yours insists on heavy scanning of newly created executables before allowing them to run.

Another possibility is that (at least) one directory in the pathname for the executable file (or for some DLL it depends upon) has a very large number of files in it. On some versions of windows, by making directories containing roughly 64k file entries in them, you can make opening files in their subdirectories arbitrarily slow.

Comment: +1 gotta be something like that, something moronic.  Still, how long would it take to scan 'Hello world'?

Comment: @MartinJames: My standard go-to answer whenever someone is experiencing pathological slowness on Windows is always "probably a virus scanner". See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5924707/fwrite-chokes-on-xml-version/5924782#5924782

Comment: Just disabled the antivirus. It worked !! The code took only 0.019 seconds. :)

Comment: WHat AV is that?  I must be sure to never use it:(

Comment: AVAST Free antivirus :(

Comment: Same problem here also! https://superuser.com/q/1662449/1430641